# C++: Return child class pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

Assuming I have an abstract base class A, and derive B from it.

With the following code:

```
A* myInst = (A*) new B;

A* GetA() { return myInst; }
B* GetB() { return (B*) myInst; }
```

The first function compiles, the second doesn't. Error: `error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'`

- Why can't I return a pointer to a child class of A?

The error also occurs if I replace the contents of the function with `return NULL;`!

Comment: The extra semicolon after the function declaration seems strange. Try removing it.

Comment: Nevermind that, the function was inline originally

Comment: Which line is that error actually referring to? You might want to show us the entirety of the code, because `;` errors can mean more than just missing semicolon (vague, yes)

Comment: You also don't need to cast a B* to an A* - the cast is implicit.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is most likely that the compiler has no idea what `A` or `B` is. Missing include most likely.

But apart from that, never ever use C-style type casting together with classes. Or even better at all.

Use `static_cast` (if you are sure that the conversion is ok) or `dynamic_cast` (if you need to check).

Comment: +1 for both a likely diagnosis and a sound advice (cannot +2 :/)

Comment: Indeed, there is something wrong with my include - it's there but the class remains undefined

Comment: Correct.  As you can see from http://codepad.org/J2WQlypM, if the compiler knows what A and B are, everything compiles.  @Parror: Check your include guards.  This happens to me when I copy a .h file but forget to update the #ifndef macro name.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of C-style casts in C++. As a rule of thumb: **never** use them. Use the appropriate C++ casts.

Apart from that, the first cast is completely redundant:

```
A* myInst = new B;

A* GetA() { return myInst; }
B* GetB() { return static_cast<B*>(myInst); }
```

This works fine.

Comment: shouldn't that be a `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: @Evan: Depends. If the code *knows* that `myInst` contains an `B` object, then `static_cast` is preferred because it conveys the meaning that we *know* the type of `myInst` (and it’s faster). `dynamic_cast` only makes sense when we don’t know the dynamic type and expect a potential failure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking the trailing semi-colon after the brace off? Eg:

```
A* myInst = (A*) new B;

A* GetA() { return myInst; }
B* GetB() { return (B*) myInst; }
```

Note: I've not tried this as I don't have access to a C++ compiler at this moment...

Comment: Yes, the semicolon was in the example because the function was inline before

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that these lines appear in separate files in your actual code, because if they appeared as shown I can't see anything wrong.

Most likely what's happening is that wherever `GetB` is defined, you forgot the include for `B` and the compiler can't figure out that it's a type.

Further, if you also used `static_cast` instead of a C-style cast the compiler would warn you if it couldn't determine the relationship between `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you should not be casting at all.

```
B bInst
A * myInst = &bInst;
A* getA() { return &bInst; }
B* getB() { return &bInst; }
```

simples!

There are rare occasions you need to cast down the hierarchy. Usually this is where you load some kind of add-on and need to check that an object is of the type you are expecting. In that case you use dynamic_cast<> to check but must have RTTI.

The other occasion occurs where you have a storage of unrelated types, eg variants / "any" types which are related only by the fact they are stored together in a single collection, and are probably handled differently once retrieved. This can also happen in a state machine. Although it may be possible to design your flow here to avoid the casts, sometimes casting is easier. In such a case though you know exactly what type you have and can static_cast down the hierarchy to it.